# How to access seekbar view from getveiw() of adapter in activity

Tags: android, listview, seekbar

I would like to access seekbar from getveiw() of adapter in activity which populates listview.

getview() in Adapter:

```
if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.seekbar= (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        viewHolder.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( myseekbarlistener);
        viewHolder.time_txt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Create one constructor like this

```
  public Top15Adapter(Top15Stocks top15Stocks, OnSeekBarChangeListener listner) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.OnSeekBarChangeListener = listher;
}


listher.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        private int progressChanged = 0;

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(Activityname.this,
                    "seek bar progress:" + progressChanged,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1,
                boolean fromuser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressChanged = arg1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please read my question again. I want to access seekbar view from activity. I know seekbarChaneListener(...)

Comment: and after adding constructor what next?

Comment: @Raja, please understand my query..adding a constructor will not change my question. I need to update seekbar progress from the activity. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update seekbar progress, then just

```
viewHolder.seekbar.setProgress(value);
```

or did you mean something else?